# Setting a single thread to real-time priority under windows

Tags: winapi

is it possible to set the priority of a single thread to real-time priority although the process does not run under real-time priority?

Answer (score 4):

The windows [scheduling priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are describing the situation clearly.
There is no thread priority called "real-time priority". The utmost priority a
thread can obtain is `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL`. But this does not completely
describe the threads base priority. This is also determined by the processes priority class.
For almost all process priority classes the setting of `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` will 
cause the thread to run in base priority of 15. One exception is the `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`.
A thread set to `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` within a process which is set to `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` runs at a base priority of 31, which is the highest priority to obtain.

The combination of `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` and `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` puts a thread already well above most other threads (also OS) but I wouldn't call this real-time.

For my point of view (and as described in the "scheduling priorities list") real-time only starts at base priorities above 15. Therefore a thread can only obtain real-time priorties, when its process has `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`.

This means the correct answer to your question is NO. A thread cannot obtain real-priority when its process has no real-time priority.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using [`SetThreadPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but [it's not recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/06/10/10022675.aspx).

Comment: sorry - this is not really helpful. The program we have requires for some threads that it's not being interrupted by any means. What I want now is a method to elevate only some of the threads without the need to elevate the whole process.

Comment: I answered the "Is it possible". I've now given a link to the API call.

Comment: actually, SetThreadPriority does not solve the problem - as you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. The scheduling priority is modified by the process priority. What I want to know is whether it is possible for a non-real-time process to run a thread that has a scheduling priority within the priority ranges of a real time process (16-31).